# Actualizar archivos .txt en C++

Tags: c++, fstream

Como se menciona en el título me interesaría actualizar un registro guardado en un archivo .txt en vez de que se cree uno cada vez que ejecuto el programa. Aquí esta mi código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

fstream archivo("Empleados.txt") ;
string nombre, apellido, direccion, telefono, dni  ;
int op1, op2 ;
do {
    cout << "Ingrese una opción:" << endl ;
    cout << endl ;
    cout << "1. Nuevo registro\n2. Salir " << endl ;
    cout << endl ;
    cin >> op1 ;
    cin.ignore() ;
    if (op1 == 1){
        if (!archivo.is_open()){
            archivo.open("Empleados.txt", ios::out) ;
        }
        system("cls") ;
        cout << "Nombre: " ;
        getline(cin, nombre) ;
        cout << "Apellido: " ;
        getline(cin, apellido) ;
        cout << "Número de documento: " ;
        cin >> dni ;
        cin.ignore() ;
        cout << "Dirección: " ;
        getline(cin, direccion) ;
        cout << "Número de teléfono: " ;
        cin >> telefono ;
        cout << endl ;

        cout << "Ingrese una opción:" ;
        cout << endl ;
        cout << "1. Guardar registro\n2. Regresar sin guardar" << endl ;
        cin >> op2 ;
        if (op2 == 1) {
            archivo << "Nombre: " << nombre << endl ;
            archivo << "Apellido: " << apellido << endl ;
            archivo << "Numero de documento: " << dni << endl ;
            archivo << "Direccion: " << direccion << endl ;
            archivo << "Numero de telefono: " << telefono << endl ;

            system("cls") ;
            cout << "Registro guardado con éxito" << endl ;
            system("pause") ;
            system("cls") ;
        }
        archivo.close() ;
    }
} while(op1 != 2);

return 0;
}
```

Desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que los registros tienen un tamaño aleatorio, no es posible actualizar solo un registro.

Lo que tienes que hacer es posicionar el puntero del archivo justo al inicio del registro a modificar y **sobreescribir** el resto del archivo, incorporando tus cambios, por supuesto.

Esto es así porque el buffer del archivo no admite el desplazamiento de caracteres, luego ese efecto que vemos en los editores de texto al insertar texto en medio de una frase no es realizable así tal cual en un archivo del sistema.

Answer (score 0):

Hasta donde se, no se puede actualizar el contenido de un txt, si se puede sobreescribir o agregar al final.
Si lo que quieres es agregar la opcion de modificar un dato guardado, podrias hacer un procedimiento que lea el archivo, identifique cada dato (algo asi como que 'despues del caracter :  guardar en el string nombre cada caracter hasta llegar al \n' y asi con cada dato.
Luego de tener cada dato en una variable, el usuario deberia elegir cual modificar y guardas el nuevo valor en la variable que corresponda.
Para finalizar, sobreescribe el archivo guardando los datos como lo hiciste en tu codigo

Para simplificar el codigo podrias hacer una funcion que solo sea para sobreescribir el archivo y reciba como parametro cada dato a registrar. (aunque es mas practico usar una estructura)